# How to write a list in front of another list in BASH/SHELL

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Summarized:
I need to know how to concatenate lists and how to calculate age with a given date of birth

Age can be just (currentYear - yearOfBirth)

I have a document like this:

(date is type of dd-mm-yyyy)

```
Name:George Jas | Date of birth:03-01-1935 | City:Amsterdam | Phone:777888999
Name:Larry Simpson | Date of birth:04-01-1956 | City:NewYork | Phone:555666777
Name:Jonh Fin | Date of birth:05-02-1930 | City:Rome | Phone:333444555
```

I need to write a document that is like this:

```
<ID>:<name>:<age>:<city>:<phone>
```

The ID is 10000+numberOfLine but I have got that already:

```
awk -F'|' -v c=10000 '{sub(/^Name/,++c); print $1}' input.txt > output.txt
```

This was easier because we just have to substitute the name by (10000 + variable) but I can't do the concatenation AND a calulation one by one to write it, so, that output.txt would be:

```
10001:George Jas:86:Amsterdam:777888999
10002:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork:555666777
10003:Jonh Fin:91:Rome:333444555
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rely on AWK for this, here is an example of AWK script to achieve it:

```
awk -F '|' -v c=10000 '
BEGIN {
"date +'%Y'" | getline current_year
} 
{
c++
split($1, name, ":")
split($2, date, "-")
split($3, city, ":")
split($4, phone, ":")
printf("%d:%s:%s:%s:%s\n",c,name[2],current_year-date[3],city[2],phone[2])
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

With your current input file, this would give a result similar to this

```
10001:George Jas :86:Amsterdam :777888999 
10002:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork :555666777 
10003:Jonh Fin :91:Rome :333444555
```

to get rid of the spaces I suggest adding a *sed* command before awk the finale command should look like this:

```
$ sed 's/ | /|/g' input.txt | awk -F '|' -v c=10000 '
BEGIN {
"date +'%Y'" | getline current_year
} 
{
c++
split($1, name, ":")
split($2, date, "-")
split($3, city, ":")
split($4, phone, ":")
printf("%d:%s:%s:%s:%s\n",c,name[2],current_year-date[3],city[2],phone[2])
}
' > output.txt
```

the result should be the one you are expecting

```
10001:George Jas:86:Amsterdam:777888999
10002:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork:555666777
10003:Jonh Fin:91:Rome:333444555
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to format with sed before running awk.
And each age can be calculated in awk.

```
sed 's/ | [^:]\+//g' input.txt | awk -F'[:-]' -v c=10000 -v n=`date +%Y%m%d` '{t=$5$3$4;print ++c":"$2":"int((n-t)/10000)":"$6":"$7}'

10001:George Jas:86:Amsterdam:777888999
10002:Larry Simpson:64:NewYork:555666777
10003:Jonh Fin:90:Rome:333444555
```

In case that age is calculated by `current Year -yearOfBirth`:

```
sed 's/ | [^:]\+//g' input.txt | awk -F'[:-]' -v c=10000 -v n=`date +%Y` '{t=$5;print ++c":"$2":"(n-t)":"$6":"$7}'

10001:George Jas:86:Amsterdam:777888999
10002:Larry Simpson:65:NewYork:555666777
10003:Jonh Fin:91:Rome:333444555
```

Comment: Thank you all very much! One thing about this one, without \+ inside sed the output was like :  Name:George Jasate of birth:86:Amsterdamhone:777888999 why is that? What does \+ mean?

Comment: `[^:]\+` is one unit. That means one or more characters that do not contain `:`. Since `+` is a special character, escape it with '\'. It can remove the `Date of birth:`, `City:` and `Phone:` parts.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for being so quick responding